# While/For Loop Mixing to output exact number of gifts

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop, modulus

So I'm trying to handle gifts for a dating site. The maximum gifts you can have are 9, and 9 gift spans must be returned, whether all 9 are returned from the db for a user who has 9 gifts, or 4 are returned from the db and the remaining 5 from the for loop, or 0 from the db and all 9 from the for loop. The mysql db is queried and a while loop outputs the gifts the user has, while a for loop takes on making sure 9 gift spans total are returned, depending on the output of the while loop (this currently does not correctly wrap):

```
$i=0;
while($row = $user_gifts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $i++;   
    $gift_name = $row["gift_name"];

    if ($i%3==1) {
      $gifts_show .= '<div>';
    }
    $gifts_show .= '<span>'.$gift_name.'</span>';   
}


    if($i<1){ //0 gifts from db, all 9 no gifts
       $i=0;
       for ($i = $i; $i < 9; $i++) {
            if ($i%3==1) $gifts_show .= '<div>';    
                $gifts_show .= '<span>No Gift.</span>';
            if ($i%3==0) $gifts_show .= '</div>';
       }
    } else { //1+ gifts from db, mix gifts with no gifts until 9 are reached
       for ($i = $i; $i < 9; $i++) {
                $gifts_show .= '<span>No Gift.</span>';
            if ($i%3==0) $gifts_show .= '</div>';
       }
    }
```

Every 3 gifts should be wrapped in a div. So the output of 9 gifts wrapped in 3 divs should look like this:

```
<div>
  <span>DB Gift 1</span> 
  <span>DB Gift 2</span> 
  <span>DB Gift 3</span> 
</div>
<div>
  <span>DB Gift 4</span> 
  <span>No Gift</span> 
  <span>No Gift</span> 
</div>
<div>
  <span>No Gift</span> 
  <span>No Gift</span> 
  <span>No Gift</span> 
</div>
```

Any idea how to output and wrap every 3 spans in a div correctly 3 times, regardless of how many gifts are outputted from the DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all about simple array manipulation.

Let's imagine I have the following array:

```
$array = array(
    'DB Gift 1',
    'DB Gift 2',
    'DB Gift 3',
    'DB Gift 4'
);
```

...but I want to show 9 elements. So firstly I pad it with "empty" elements:

```
$array = array_pad($array, 9, 'No Gift');
```

...and I want to show it in 3 blocks of 3. So I split it into 3 blocks:

```
$array = array_chunk($array, 3);
```

...and now it's just a simple case of joining it all together. So firstly I join all the inner elements:

```
foreach ($array as &$block) {
    $block = '<span>'.implode('</span><span>', $block).'</span>';
}
```

...and then I join the outer elements:

```
$result = '<div>'.implode('</div><div>', $array).'</div>';
```

Job done.

[See it working](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EIOA2x)

Comment: The example works great, Thank you Dave! But what would the while loop look like for the db results with respect to the db array elements so it works? Also, this all goes outside the while loop, correct?

Comment: @Maveric I would imagine `$array = array(); while ($row = $user_gifts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { $array[] = $row["gift_name"]; }` will populate the array with what you need